# ReactJs Pass argument from component to component

Tags: reactjs

I am still learning ReactJs and I stumbled upon a problem. I have rendered Header Content and Footer as different components. And when user logs in in ComponentDidMount of Content I get Json with his name, surname etc.. And when I receive the data I would like to add users name to header like Welcome, `username` . But I dont know how to pass that or where so that the component Header gets the name.

**Index**

```
render: function() {

if(this.state.signup == true) {
  return  (
    <div>
    <Header data = {this.state.signup} logout={this.logOut}/>
    <MenuBar/>
      <Content/>
     <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
} else {
  return  (
    <div>
     <Header data = {this.state.signup}/>
    <MenuBar/>
      <Login func={this.logIn}/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
},
```

So if user is logged in the states changes to true. And that opens Content.
Here I get userdata

**Content**

```
componentDidMount: function() {
document.title = "Dashboard";
this.getUser();

 },

 getUser: function(){
 $.getJSON(url, this.handleData);
},

handleData: function(data){
 this.setState({data: data});
 },
```

And now when this happens I would like to change the header with Welcome, `Name of the user` from Json.

**Header**

```
render() {
if(this.props.data) //Check if user is logged in
{
  return (
  <section className="heading">
            <div className="user-message">Welcome, User</div> //Here i would like to change user name from Json         
  </section> 
);

 }
else{
  return (
        <section className="heading">
            <div className="user-message">You are not connected</div>
        </section>
  );
```

I dont know if I understood ReactJs completely so I might went into the wrong direction.

So how should I change the name? I thought about moving Header To Content And pass from there, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of return statement in if else, I will suggest to create a new component called UserMessage

```
class UserMessage extends Component{
  render(){
     return <div className="user-message">{this.props.message}</div>
   }
}
```

And in Header,

```
{
this.props.data?<UserMessage message={this.props.data.message}/>:<UserMessage message="You are not connected"/>
}
```

I have used this in similar use-case where I have to show loadingBar when data is not available.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is register an dispatcher on componentDidMount for each component, and when your user logged-in, your userStore should emit an event, and your components have just to update there state putting the user logged.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.